# How to tell the Facebook sharer to ignore images?

Tags: facebook-sharer

I want Facebook's share.php to ignore certain images for the page thumbnail.

It should scrape my page as it does (without an og:image meta tag for a certain default thumb).

Is there an attribute I can add to the image or a container div?

I don't want to f*** up my page with javascript just for the share scraper tho.

Comment: see also see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810564/ignore-image-when-sharing-a-page-with-facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sharer.php is deprecated and should no longer be used.  Facebook could completely remove it at any time.

For the like, it uses og tags.  Just specify the og:image tag in the head section of your html, no javascript required to change the image tag  :)

Comment: As mentioned it should just scrape the page as usual. I won't add og tags just for Facebook ;)

Comment: og tags are for _more_ than just Facebook.  It's an open standard see ogp.me for more information.  They don't add much payload at all to the html code. as for an attribute to an existing image, no, there's not...that's what the og tags are for.