# How to prevent Facebook from pulling random images from your site when you share?

Tags: html, facebook, image, markup

I have no images on my blog. The only JPG on the whole page is a tiny little Twitter icon. So what happens when I share that blog post is Facebook uses that little Twitter icon as the featured image for the post. Very awkward.

Any ways to force certain images to be ignored?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignore image when sharing a page with Facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810564/ignore-image-when-sharing-a-page-with-facebook)

Answer (score 5):

You want to use [Open Graph Meta Tags](http://swarminglabs.com/facebook-open-graph-meta-tags/) to specify an image. Without specifying an image, Facebook will attempt to parse all of your images to get content.

You can check how Facebook parses your page [via their debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

Answer (score -3):

use css if possible to declare the undesired image (+div)

Comment: well the css is the only option i see to declace a (background) image invisible for facebook .. else use the open graph tags sure to force the picture taken .. take care the facebook parser is "buggy" means it wants big pictures and if your open graph picture is small it will take another one if there is a big one on the page .. also the switcher is atm aik broken to select a diffent picture from multiple declarations