# How to mark an image to NOT show on social networks?

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-opengraph

I'm working on a classified ads website, where people post ads, and obviously, sometimes photos. When they do post photos, everything is fine. I have `og:image` meta tags which list the images for social networks to use when the post is shared.

However, I also have paid premium ads which show up at the bottom of the page on each post. The premium ads, of course, also contain images. If a person doesn't upload any photos with their ad, then the images for the paid ads show up in the social network share.

How can I mark those images to not show up on the social network when the link is shared? I'd rather the link appear without an image on a social feed than the wrong image, especially if the user didn't provide one.

Here's [an example post](https://new-york.yanteres.com/community/help/carhk8my) that my coworker tried to share that led to much cursing about the wrong images.

Answer (score 0):

You should ALWAYS define an `og:image` tag. If there is no image to show, just use a fallback image. That way, other pictures will be ignored.

This is also suggested in another thread, btw: [Exclude image from Open Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27618936/exclude-image-from-open-graph)

Comment: I had a fallback image specified, which was only 180x180 pixels, so I made a new fallback image that was 1200x630. That seemed to fix it. Apparently Facebook will now ignore images under a certain resolution, as it used to work in the past.

Comment: earlier, the minimum was 200x200, but that was some years ago.